# Quick way to store a URL in the browser's history

Tags: javascript, browser-history

Is there a quicker way to store a URL (or actually a set of URLs, hence my question) in the browser's history, than making an element such as an iframe load a webpage using the src attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the HTML5 History API.  Here are some good resources to get started:

http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/a-first-look-at-the-history-api/

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introducing-the-html5-history-api/

Comment: What use case do you have where you are running into performance issues with the History API?